# Can a SQL Stored Procedure drop itself and continue execution?

Tags: sql

Specifically, can I do this?

```
CREATE PROC AutoDestructiveStoredProcedure
AS
DROP PROC AutoDestructiveStoredProcedure
PRINT 'Still alive.'
GO
```

Is it a bad practice?

What is the expected behavior? Does it change based on implementation?
What would be the difference between executing this in SQL Server, MySQL and Oracle?

Comment: Which DBMS? SQLServer? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: It is a just for fun question, I can't actually imagine a case where it could be useful.

Comment: `Is it a bad practice?` - definitely, YES.

Comment: This procedure will self-destruct in 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. BANG!

Comment: I think this will be useful for running some kind of one time batch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this will work -- at least in SQL Server 2008 R2.  It continues executing until the end of the procedure and after that the procedure is gone.

Is it bad practice?  I think so.  In my mind, the main reason is that it mixes DDL with DML, imposing unexpected side effects on what is normally a well-understood operation (calling a stored procedure).

Unfortunately, I can't answer your question with respect to how it works on MySQL or Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this not sure why you would want to

```
CREATE PROC AutoDestructiveStoredProcedure
AS
PRINT 'Being killed'
DROP PROC AutoDestructiveStoredProcedure
PRINT 'Still alive.'
exec createAutoDestruct
print 'Alive Again'
GO

create proc createAutoDestruct as

Exec sp_executesql N'CREATE PROC AutoDestructiveStoredProcedure
AS
PRINT ''Being killed''
DROP PROC AutoDestructiveStoredProcedure
PRINT ''Still alive.''
exec createAutoDestruct
print ''Alive Again'' '
GO


AutoDestructiveStoredProcedure
AutoDestructiveStoredProcedure
```

Answer (score 1):

I've gathered the following experimental evidence in Oracle. I created the following procedure:

```
create procedure selfdestruct is
begin
execute immediate 'drop procedure selfdestruct';
end selfdestruct;
```

Then, ran it using

```
exec selfdestruct;
```

The result appears to be a never-ending procedure. A brief look at the database activity reveals that the session is waiting on `library cache pin`, which appears to be the method that Oracle uses to prevent an procedural object from changing while it is in-use.

In brief, for Oracle, the answer is "No, you can't drop a procedure while it is running."

Comment: Now that's interesting. I will dig deeper and probably ask another crazy question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple: I work on a database of which I am not the administrator and I do not want other people to see and edit my SP, so I create it at runtime from the program before running it and at the end I have to delete it in order not to leave it in the database.

Comment: Your answer doesn't really answer the OP's question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

you could use the self destruct to not forget objects on customers base
this will work  in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) and on Oracle 11G(probaly 10g too)

on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2)

```
CREATE PROC AutoDestructiveStoredProcedure
AS
PRINT 'Being killed'
DROP PROC AutoDestructiveStoredProcedure
PRINT 'Still alive.'
print 'Alive Again'
GO


select OBJECT_ID('AutoDestructiveStoredProcedure')
```

--1243151474

```
exec AutoDestructiveStoredProcedure
```

--Being killed

--Still alive.

--Alive Again

```
select OBJECT_ID('AutoDestructiveStoredProcedure')
```

--null

On oracle

```
SET serveroutput ON size unlimited;

 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE selfdestruct
 AS
   v_plSqlBlock varchar2(500);
   v_job_int binary_integer;
     BEGIN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Being killed');

     v_plSqlBlock  :=' 
     BEGIN
     execute immediate ''drop procedure selfdestruct'';
     END;
     ';

       dbms_job.submit(
                   job =>  v_job_int,
                   what => v_plSqlBlock
                   );     
     commit;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Still alive.');
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Alive Again');
     END selfdestruct;
     /



 SELECT count(1)
 FROM dba_procedures
 WHERE object_name = upper('selfdestruct');
```